# app.config.from_pyfile() is turning values into tuples?

Tags: flask

I'm running into something confusing with Flask 10.1.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('local.cfg')
app.config.update(dict(
  BAR = 'bar',
))
```

where local.cfg is

```
FOO = 'foo'
BAR = 'bar'
```

I get

```
app.config['FOO'] => ('foo',)
app.config['BAR'] => 'bar'
```

Am I doing something wrong that's turning FOO into a tuple?

Answer (score 7):

Well, that was embarrassing. I was suffering a case of comma blindness. For the benefit of anyone else who stumbles into this problem, having a stray comma in a configuration file causes tuples. That is,

```
FOO = 'foo'
```

works as expected. But type

```
FOO = 'foo',
```

and things go sideways, since `app.config['FOO'] == ('foo',)`